# pugiXML to locate child that has the same parents value

Tags: c++, pugixml

So my XML is as followed

```
<level1>
    <level2>
          <hero1>
          </hero1>
    </level2>
    <level2>
          <hero2>
          </hero2>
    </level2>
</level1>
```

Now I want to access `hero2`, but when I do, suppose `doc` is my XML data

`doc.child("level1").child("level2").child("hero2")`

It return `false`, which means that it couldn't locate my `hero2`. How could I find it?

Answer (score 1):

Lets consider your XML file. When you call:

```
  doc.child("level1").child("level2").child("hero2");
```

It is equivalent to:

```
  element1 = doc.child("level1").child("level2");
  element  =  element1.child("hero2");
```

Lets see:

```
pugi::xml_node element1 = doc.child("level1").child("level2");
// Element 1 gives you first node "level2"

// Element 2 does not have child ("hero2") so the call will return NULL
pugi::xml_node element2 = element1.child("hero2"); // element2 is NULL

// Element 2 has a child "hero1"
// So you can get it as:
pugi::xml_node element2child_hero1 = element1.child("hero1"); //
```

But you want to get "hero2" not "hero1".

One of the solutions for your particular file is presented below.
The for loop goes via all siblings till "hero2" is found:

```
int findHero2(const char *file)
{
    pugi::xml_document doc;
    if (!doc.load_file(file)) return -1; 

    pugi::xml_node level1 = doc.child("level1");

    for (pugi::xml_node level2 = level1.first_child(); level2; level2 = level2.next_sibling())
    {
        pugi::xml_node node = level2.child("hero2");
        if(node!=NULL)
        {
            // I have found "hero2" node
            // ... 
           return 0; // success
        }
    }

    return -2; // no "hero2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer in terms of algorithm: if you (potentially) have several children with the same name, iterate over them using `first_child(name)` and `next_sibling(name)`.